# Sierra - Image Capture PDF file size too large

Tags: macos, pdf, image-capture

Since upgrading to MacOS Sierra, the PDFs I scan with Image Capture are much larger.  My typical settings are 8.5x11 size, 300 DPI, "Text".  With Yosemite, an average page of text was around 100KB.  Now, an average page is around 1MB - 10x larger file size with no noticeable difference in quality.

Examining the scanned PDFs in Acrobat Pro, I see that the new one is using 8-bit grayscale.  Previously, in Yosemite, it used 1-bit.  Now there seems to be no difference between the two Image Capture options: `Text` and `Black & White`.

Is there any way to get 1-bit PDF scanning back?  As a workaround, I am now using PNG for now, which has smaller file sizes.

[image]

Comment: Might be helpful to see a screenshot of your scan dialog settings.

Comment: Added, although I had already described all the settings.

Comment: Sierra changed the behavior of this box, do you always use the detailed view?

Comment: Yes I always use the detailed view

Comment: My suspicion is that the embedded image in the PDF is different somehow, but I'm not aware of a way to permanently fix it if that is true.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: What version of PDF is it using?  To get PDF version number, open file in Preview and under tools menu select 'show inspector'. A window pops up and gives info about the file, including PDF version number.

Comment: In both Yosemite and Sierra, it uses PDF version 1.3

Comment: This is still a problem on Catalina, so I finally reported to Apple as a bug